# Convergence notary server error

Tags: openssl, convergence

Trying to run a convergence notary to learn some stuff and I get an error when starting the service. I am running Ubuntu server 11.04 fully updated. I followed the directions that are [here](https://github.com/moxie0/Convergence/wiki/Running-a-Notary).

When I start the service I get the following error:

```
@www:~$ sudo service convergence start
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 32768.
Starting convergence notary: convergence...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/convergence-notary", line 236, in <module>
  main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/local/bin/convergence-notary", line 215, in main
interface=incomingInterface)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 444, in listenSSL
p.startListening()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 854, in startListening
skt = self.createInternetSocket()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/ssl.py", line 196, in createInternetSocket
return SSL.Connection(self.ctxFactory.getContext(), sock)

File "/usr/local/bin/convergence-notary", line 71, in getContext
ctx.use_certificate_chain_file(self.cert)

OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'No such file or directory'), ('BIO routines', 'FILE_CTRL', 'system lib'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file', 'system lib')]
```

---

**note** I'm using ports 8080 and 8081 because I already have 80 taken up by apache running my webserver, and 8081 because I have openSSL running for my webpage on 443. Besides, convergence doesn't care as long as your bundle info is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, this may not be a permanent fix, but good enough for now. Use the following command to make it work:

```
sudo convergence-notary -p 8080 -s 8081 -c /etc/ssl/certs/mynotary.pem -k /etc/ssl/private/convergence.key
```